# c# split string and remove empty string

Tags: c#

I want to remove empty and null string in the split operation:

```
 string number = "9811456789,   ";
 List<string> mobileNos = number.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(mobile => mobile.Trim()).ToList();
```

I tried this but this is not removing the empty space entry

Comment: Before selecting clean up the list with `.Where(x => !x.IsNullOrEmpty()).Select( ...)`

Comment: but its not empty it has spaces in .. you could add a where clause to remove them

Comment: @AntonSizikov should be `!x.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`....

Comment: Yup, it should.

Answer (score 78):

```
var mobileNos = number.Replace(" ", "")
.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

Answer (score 15):

As I understand it can help to you;

```
string number = "9811456789, ";
List<string> mobileNos = number.Split(',').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();
```

the result only one element in list as [0] = "9811456789".

Hope it helps to you.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest and best solution is to use both `StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries` to trim the results and `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to remove empty entries, fed in through the pipe operator (`|`).

```
string number = "9811456789,   ";
List<string> mobileNos = number
    .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries | StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .ToList();
```

Checkout the below test results to compare how each option works,

[image]

Comment: Note that `StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries` is only available in `.NET 5+`

Answer (score 6):

a string extension can do this in neat way as below 
the extension :

```
        public static IEnumerable<string> SplitAndTrim(this string value, params char[] separators)
        {
            Ensure.Argument.NotNull(value, "source");
            return value.Trim().Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Trim());
        }
```

then you can use it with any string as below

```
 char[] separator = { ' ', '-' };
 var mobileNos = number.SplitAndTrim(separator);
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old question, but the following works just fine:

```
string number = "9811456789,   ";
List<string> mobileNos = number.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

No need for extension methods or whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

```
"string,,,,string2".Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

return ["string"],["string2"]

Comment: Please provide some explanation why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.

Comment: @PeterCsala the answer is wrong but explains about as much as the other answers since the code speaks for itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linq. This work for me.

```
string temp = "a,b,   ,c,  ";    
List<string> result = temp.Split(',').Where(i => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i) == false).ToList();
```