# How do I get rid of double spaces without regex or any external methods?

Tags: c#, whitespace, palindrome, removing-whitespace

This is an extra exercise given to us on our Uni course, in which we need to find whether a sentence contains a palindrome or not. Whereas finding if a word is a palindrome or not is fairly easy, there could be a situation where the given sentence looks like this: "Dog cat - kajak house". My logic is to, using functions I already wrote, first determine if a character is a letter or not, if not delete it. Then count number of spaces+1 to find out how many words there are in a sentence, prepare an array of those words and then cast a function that checks if a word is palindrome on every element of an array. However, the double space would mess everything up on a "counting" phase. I've spent around an hour fiddling with code to do this, however I can't wrap my head around this. Could anyone help me? Note that I'm not supposed to use any external methods or libraries. I've done this using RegEx and it was fairly easy, however I'd like to do this "legally". Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's illegal about regex and please post some code for us to work with

Comment: Jakub, you can just STATE what you want to do  :)  No need to explaiun your project etc.  :)  google .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467258/c-sharp-split-string-and-remove-empty-string

Comment: Regex is illegal in a way that it requires using System.Text.RegularExpressions; to work. I got if(sentence[i] == ' '){ if(i!=sentence.Length-1 && sentence[i+1] == ' '){ //want to pop one whitespace}} however I don't know if there is a way to "pop" this element out.

Comment: Re: *"I'm not supposed to use any external methods or libraries"*.  What makes a method or library *external*?  Is `string.Length` external (its getter and setter methods are in the `System.dll`, what about `StringBuilder` (in `System.Text.dll`)?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just get rid of all the spaces?  I thought palindromic sentences didn't need for the symmetry to include spaces and punctuation.  As I understand it, sentences like *""Sit on a potato pan, Otis"* are consider palindromes.

Comment: Flydog57, the thing is not to check if a sentence is a palindrome, but if a sentence contains words that are palindromes.

Answer (score 2):

Just split on space, the trick is to remove empties.  Google `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

then obviously join with one clean space

Answer (score 0):

You could copy all the characters you are interested in to a new string:

```
var copy = new StringBuilder();

// Indicates whether the previous character was whitespace
var whitespace = true;

foreach (var character in originalString)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(character))
    {
        copy.Append(character);
        whitespace = false;
    }
    else if (char.IsWhiteSpace(character) && !whitespace)
    {
        copy.Append(character);
        whitespace = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Ignore other characters
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the most rudimentary/olde-worlde option, this will work. But no-one would actually do this, other than in an illustrative manner.

```
string test = "Dog cat       kajak house"; // Your string minus any non-letters
int prevLen;
do
{
    prevLen = test.Length;
    test = test.Replace("  ", " "); // Repeat-replace double spaces until none left
} while (prevLen > test.Length);
```

Personally, I'd probably do the following to end up with an array of words to check:

```
string[] words = test.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: This would be a great solution, however, as I said, I need all methods to be "mine", so .Replace() is not going to pass it. This is the main problem.

Comment: @JakubSapko Then you'd kinda have to write your own programming language - that's a *very* artificial restriction. You are even using `Length` in your sample code, which is in the same `mscorlib` System library as `Replace` I believe.

Comment: Yeah, Length is the only thing we are actually able to use from the string-related methods.

Comment: `Length` is a String property, `Replace` is a String method, same library (mscorlib.dll), same namespace (System). Are you sure you haven't misunderstood what's being asked of you? I'll have to leave it there, I'm afraid, as the question isn't a real-life one.

Comment: Whatever it's called, I'm just tired at this point lmao. All of used methods must be written by us, so Replace is invalid no matter what.