# How can I delete semicolons empty?

Tags: c#

I am an intern, I am programming in C# right now and I have to retrieve a string of characters from an excel file. But this string of characters is too long, in fact, it's a list that separates elements by semicolons. But is possible that the list contains blank space between two semicolons, and I want to delete these extra semicolons because it will be easier for me to treat the list

How can I do it, do I have to use a specific method? Really I tried, but i am not able to find a solution, that's why I am asking you for help.

This is an example of the list in excel :

```
 ; QC4 1000 ppm ; C-191108-S-0095 ; C-191108-S-0095 ; QC4 100 ppm ; QC4 1000 ppm ; Et 500 ppm ; Et 1000 ppm ; Et 2000 ppm ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;
```

As you can see there are extra semicolons that are unuseful for the treatments. The list can be much longer or much shorter than the example I gave. That's why I want to implement a code that detects that there is nothing between 2 semicolons, and delete the extras.

I did this :

```
string input = " ; QC4 1000 ppm ; C-191108-S-0095 ; C-191108-S-0095 ; QC4 100 ppm ; QC4 1000 ppm ; Et 500 ppm ; Et 1000 ppm ; Et 2000 ppm ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ";
            input.Replace("; ;", " ");
            Console.WriteLine(input);
```

But it's not working

Comment: You might want to consider removing semicolons only form the end, to avoid misaligned data when some cell is empty

Comment: In your input there are two whitespaces between the semicolons, but you look only for two semicolons with one whitespace between each other. You should use regex to be more flexible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# split string and remove empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467258/c-sharp-split-string-and-remove-empty-string)

Comment: Between the "extra" semi-colons there are two spaces instead of one.

Comment: To convert to a list, use `var list = input.Split(new string[] { " ; " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`. If I'm not mistaken, that appears to be your end goal, right?

Comment: `var clean = string.Join(" ; ", s.Split(new string[] { " ; " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));`

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I have to to test them all to see which suits the best. A last question, can we delete the empty semi-colons instead of replacing them by a blank space ?

Answer (score 2):

You have two spaces between the semicolons. Try to use the next code:

```
string output = input.Replace(";  ;", " ");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

An other method is to use a regular expression:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@";\s+;");
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(input, " "));
```

A third version, it deletes the all the spaces from the beginning and the end of the string:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@";\s+;|^\s+;");
Console.WriteLine("#" + regex.Replace(input, "").Trim() + "#");
```

The fourth version:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\s*;\s*)+|(\s*;\s*)+$");
string output = regex.Replace(input, "");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it's working correctly, but can we do it also for the first semi colon in the debut of the list in the example ?

Comment: You can change the regexp: Regex regex = new Regex(@";\s+;|^\s+;");

Comment: Sorry, but your regex is not working. I implemented it but there is always the first semicolon in the list

Comment: Please try the fourth version.

Comment: thank you very much it's working perfectly