# element of separator and split function

Tags: c#, string, split

I saw this in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0

> Each element of separator defines a separate delimiter character. If
> two delimiters are adjacent, or a delimiter is found at the beginning
> or end of this instance, the corresponding element in the returned
> array contains Empty.

```
    string str = "Hello.. How.. are.. you?";
    string[] words = str.Split(new char[] { '.' });
    foreach (string s in words)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
```

Outputs are: Hello "" How "" are "" you?

```
    string str = "Hello. How. are. you?";
    string[] words = str.Split(new char[] { '.' });
    foreach (string s in words)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
```

Outputs are: Hello  How  are  you?

Why does this happen?

Comment: What do you mean? Why wouldn't it happen? Between `.` and `.` in `..` there is an empty string.

Comment: I can not understand properly. Another example: `str = "42..12..19."`  `output = {"42", "", "12", "", "19", ""}`

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand. Can you provide more details about what's confusing you about this scenario? For every `.`, you get a new string either side of it. So a string with 6 `.`, when split, will produce an array of 7 strings. A string with 2 `.`, when split, will produce an array of 3 strings.

Comment: Even `"......"` will produce an array of 7 (empty) strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# split string and remove empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467258/c-sharp-split-string-and-remove-empty-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your split character is `.`:

```
string[] words = str.Split(new char[] { '.' });
```

(the parameter is an array, because you can supply *multiple different* characters to split on - it does **not** mean it splits "on an array of dots" if that was your assumption)

So .NET splits accordingly at *every* dot character:

```
Hello.. How.. are.. you?
     ^^    ^^    ^^
```

The first part is `Hello`, that gets terminated by the first dot.
The second part is a string of 0 length, because it gets terminated immediately by the second dot.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me about this example why it shows empty space twice for two endpoints?

`string str = "Hello..  How..  are..  you?..";`

Comment: Do you mean what happens with the space characters before `How`? They get included, so after processing the `Hello..` part, it will show `"  How"` as the 3rd part. You could use `.Trim()` on each part if you want to remove the space characters, ie `MessageBox.Show(s.Trim());` (I'm not quite sure if that's what you meant)

Comment: Thank you. Why we see `""` and `""` after `" you?"`

Comment: @user2111639 Do you understand why "Hello.. How" produces `["Hello", "", " How"]` as opposed to `["Hello", " How"]`?

Comment: When we use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, these empty spaces are removed. My question is why more space is shown when we add a dot to the end or beginning of a string (`string str = ".Hello..  How..  are..  you?."`).