# How to remove double comma from textbox in .NET framework C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string, textbox

I want to make textbox where user can input decimals, e.g. "1, 2, 3, 4". Then I split this into integer array using

```
array = Array.ConvertAll(str.Split(','), int.Parse);
```

When user input e.g. "1,,,,2,,3,4" there is en exception. How can I remove commas when string is immutable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# split string and remove empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467258/c-sharp-split-string-and-remove-empty-string)

Answer (score 5):

You can't remove the commas from the existing string - although you could create a *different* string before splitting. That's typically what you do with string processing - create a whole sequence of strings, performing replacements, trimming etc along the way.

A simpler solution is probably to use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` though:

```cs
string[] parts = str.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
array = Array.ConvertAll(parts, int.Parse);
```

(Note that the `String.Split(char, StringSplitOptions)` overload is not available in the desktop framework; you'd need to call `String.Split(char[], StringSplitOptions)` - just change `','` to `new[] { ',' }` in the calling code.)

You could potentially include `StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries` too, so that "1, 2 , 3   ,4" would be handled equivalently to "1,2,3,4".

This is assuming you *just* want to handle users adding more commas than expected. It won't help if the user enters "1,2,xyz" for example.